# How come I get internal server error even with try catch for get_the_title in functions.php?

Tags: title, 500-internal-error, get-the-title

I'm relatively new to PHP & wordpress but not to programming.

I wanted to have a title relative to the `$post` title, so I created the following filter and added it to `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle');
function filter_pagetitle($title) {
    global $post;
    return $title . $post->post_title;
}
```

However, the title was still the same as `$title`, didn't concatenate with the post title, so I took on another approach, using `get_the_title()`:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle');
function filter_pagetitle($title) {
    global $post;
    return $title . get_the_title();
}
```

However, this caused `500 - internal server error` (even if I replaced with `get_the_title($post->ID)`), so I thought of catching the error and just concatenate the current fixed title with `"error"`:

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'filter_pagetitle');
function filter_pagetitle($title) {
    global $post;

    try {
        $toReturn = $title . get_the_title();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $toReturn = $title . " error";
    }
    return $toReturn;
}
```

Yet I still got the 500 internal server error. 
I ended up writing this in the header.php, which finally works:

```
 <title>Some fixed title | <?php echo get_the_title();  ?></title>
```

However, why didn't it work in `functions.php`? Am I declaring a new variable incorrectly? Or am I doing the concatenation incorrectly?

Comment: By the way, if you're wondering why I don't just look at  the stacktrace, it's because I don't know how to do that yet (the server is somewhere remotely and I only have access to wp-admin and the ftp). Concatenating with `"error"` (or even `$e->getMessage()`) was my attempt to see the why, but I still had an error

Comment: if you do not have access to error log file, you can not do much development, at least not proper one, although you should set `WP_DEGUB` to `true` and that might help with displaying the errors. Anyway sounds like you have an endless recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid hard coded title tag in your theme template. Just use [theme support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag).

```
add_theme_support('title-tag');
```

OR, If you want to use title tag then you can do something like this.

```
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right');?></title>
```

You can then apply filter as

```
/**
 * Filters wp_title to print a neat <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
 *
 * @param string $title Default title text for current view.
 * @param string $sep   Optional separator.
 * @return string The filtered title.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    global $page, $paged;

    // Add the blog name
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title .= " $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $title .= " $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', '_s' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpdocs_theme_name_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

See [wp_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/)

Comment: definitely +1 - but was the lack of `add_theme_support('title-tag');` the reason for the 500 error?

Comment: I don't think so. You should set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in `wp-config.php` file to get the proper php error.